# Improving a sentence without changing its idea

Tags: relative-pronouns

Here is my sentence,

> regular objects can be geometrically modelled by intersecting ridges
>   *themselves* and also with other boundary segments.

I feel this "themselves" degrade the quality of sentence or idea. *I want to tell that objects can be modeled by intersecting ridges and ridges, and also ridges and other boundary line segments.*

Is there  any other way to explain this idea?

Comment: Seems "Too Localized". It might be a good question for chat, but not as an ELL question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following.

> Regular objects can be geometrically modeled by ridges intersecting either other ridges, or boundary segments.

The *other* is the key innovation here, as it makes it separates the two "groups" of ridges.